# Urn problem with equal amount of balls

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let an urn containing $n$ white balls, $n$ black balls, we extract two-by-two without replacement balls from the urn. Whats the probability of extracting each time a white and black ball.
Here is my approach let $W_i$ denote the event of extracting a white ball, $B_i $ the event of extracting a black ball at the i-th extraction
thus $P(W_i \cap B_i) = \frac{\frac{1}{4} \cdot (C^1_{2(n-i+1)})^2}{C^2_{2(n-i+1)}}$ thus the whole probability of extracting each time two balls to be of different color is the product of this probability since each extraction is independent from its previous: we get $$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (W_i \cap B_i)) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\frac{1}{4} \cdot (C^1_{2(n-i+1)})^2}{C^2_{2(n-i+1)}}$$
is this valid?

Comment: You may test your answer using $n=1$.

Comment: @peterwhy ah so im wrong but i dont know how to fix my problem then

Comment: @peterwhy check now the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can imagine that the balls are sorted in advance and the balls are removed from the sequence pair by pair from the left (or from the right - this does not matter).

There are
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}
$$
ways to order the balls. From them only $2^n$ combinations correspond to the required one (the number of ways to order $n$ pairs of $wb$ or $bw$). Thus the probability in question is
$$
\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}.\tag1
$$

> UPDATE: The same result can be obtained in a more conventional way without using combinatorics. Assume that there are $k$ balls of each color in the urn. Then the probability to extract a white and a black ball is $$P_k=2\frac k{2k}\cdot\frac k{2k-1}=\frac k{2k-1},$$ so that the probability in question is $$\prod_{k=n}^1 P_k=\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!!},$$ which coinsides with $(1)$.

Comment: If we split up $(2n)!$ into $(2n)!! \cdot (2n-1)!!$, then $(2n)!! =2^n \cdot n!$, so we can write the probability as $\frac{n!}{(2n-1)!!}$. Arguably simpler, though it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you for this remark, Misha! I remember a joke about an entrance examination in my university, where an abiturient cry loudly the numbers from the exam ticket and being asked about the reason of this strange behavior said that there are exclamation signs after every second number... How loud would he be seeing two exclamation signs? :)

Comment: Pared to the bone, user and Misha !!

Comment: @trueblueanil can you please explain to me where did the 2^n factor came from?

Comment: @user can you write your elegant solution in a conditional probability way ?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Could you clarify what condition do you mean?

Comment: @user dont bother at all with my request, last question pleaaase, can you please explain to me where did the 2^n factor came from?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI This is the number of ways to order n pairs of $wb$ or $bw$. You can think it as a binary sequence where for example $wb\mapsto0$, $bw\mapsto1$.

Comment: so we have the set of outcomes $\{wb, bw, ww, bb\}$ i see that we have two similar outcomes, and we want to get those outcomes n times, thus i had the logic of multiplying 2 , n times @user is this wrong logic?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI I don't quite understand your logic. The required "outcome" in my solution is the sequence $(wb)(bw)\dots(wb)$ with both possible permutations of $b$ and $w$ inside each bracket.

Comment: but i dont understand where does the factor of without replacement comes in play @user? Why the hypergeometric law isnt used here?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI I have explained this in the answer. You consider that the sequence is already constructed in advance (all sequences of $2n$ balls have the same probability). Then you imagine that you take pair by pair from the left (or from the right - this does not matter).

Comment: and the probability of all the sequences of 2n balls is $\frac{1}{C^n_{2n}}$? @user

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Yes, though I prefer notation $\binom{2n}n$.

Comment: ah okey also can you emphasize on the point `magine that you take pair by pair from the left (or from the right - this does not matter)` please, tysm @user

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Do you want me to add this to my answer?

Comment: yes please that would be extremely helpful @user

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Done.

Comment: OMG thats beautiful, but i think im too dumb to understand why the factor of two you multiplied with in the first expression of $P_k$ @user

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI Because the first ball can be either black or white.

Comment: aaaaa thats somewhat related to the $bw, wb$ you mentioned, fully grasped now thank you so much @user

Answer (score 1):

I think your formulation can be simplified to

$$\Large P=\prod_{i=n}^1\frac {S_i}{H_i}$$

where $S_i$ and $H_i$ are square numbers and hexagonal numbers respectively.

I don't understand the factor of $1/4$ in your formulation

Comment: the factor of 1/4 is coming from the product of the probability of choosing both a black and a white ball (1/2 times 1/2 times the square of the number of ways of choose two balls out of n-i+1 ball remaining

Comment: When n each of each color are there. won't the Pr be $\Large\frac{\binom{n}1\binom{n}1}{\binom{2n}2}$ ?